# Problem to upload several images per one request

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data, form-data

I have the following controller's action:

```
    [HttpPost("api/v1/addProduct")]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public Task<ProductDto?> AddProduct([FromForm] ProductRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _productService.AddProduct(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

and the following model:

```
public class ProductRequest
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PreviewDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IFormFile PreviewImage { get; set; }

    public IFormFile[]? Images { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int[] CategoryIds { get; set; }
    
    public bool? IsAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

I successfully sent data to the server (I use formData):

[image]

But by some reason, I see the following in the debugger:

[image]

Everything is ok with `previewImage` but where are `images`? Why `previewImage` is here, but there is no `images`? I sent them in exactly the same way as I sent `previewImage`. We can see it at the request payload screen. Help me please to figure it out.

**UPDATE**

I tried `IFormFileCollection`:

[image]

No result.

But:

[image]

As we can see here (using `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files`) I see all the files. What is wrong with binding?

I can solve it in this way:

[image]

But it looks awful. Model binding must work here! Why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. I used wrong name for `images`. I have to use `images` instead of `images[]`:

[image]

This is a bit strange, because as you can see I have `categoryIds[]` it is an array, and it works as expected.

Now I see:

[image]